# Properties of Asymptotic analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions, asymptotics

I have a simple question.

We usually use ~ notation if two functions are asymptotically equivalent.

My question is, does summation, subtraction, multiplication, and composition of functions preserve the ~ notation?

i.e.

if $f_1(x)\sim g_1(x)$ and $f_2(x) \sim g_2(x)$, is it true that $f_1+f_2 \sim g_1+g_2$,
$f_1-f_2 \sim g_1-g_2 $,$f_1*f_2 \sim g_1*g_2$, and $f_1(f_2)\sim g_1(g_2)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is compatible only with

- limits: if $\ell\ne0$, $\displaystyle\lim_af=\ell\iff f\sim_a=\ell$
- products
- integer powers
- inverse
- quotients
- antiderivative: more precisely, if $f\sim_ag$, then $\displaystyle\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mut\sim_a\int_a^xg(t)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mut$
- right composition by the same function: if $\;\displaystyle\lim_a g=b$ and $f_1\sim_bf_2$, then $\;f_1\circ g\sim_a f_2\circ g$
- left composition by logarithm: if in a neighbourhood of $a$, $\dfrac1{\ln\circ g}\;$  is bounded, and $f\sim_ag$, then $\;\ln\circ f\sim_a\ln\circ g$.
- left composition by the exponential function: if $\;\displaystyle\lim_a(f-g)=0$, then $\;\mathrm e^f\sim_a\mathrm e^g$.

It is *not* compatible with sums: $x+x^2\sim_0 x$, $-x+x^3\sim_0-x$, but $(x+x^2)+(-x+x^3)\nsim_0 0$.

It is *not*  compatible with derivatives either: $f(x)=1+2x\sim_01\sim_0g(x)=1+x$, but $f'(x)=2\nsim_0g'(x)=1$.

Comment: Do you know a reference where such properties of asymptotics are treated in detail? It seems that in most real analysis books this isn't done.

Comment: If you read French, there [this Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op%C3%A9rations_sur_les_%C3%A9quivalents). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an English equivalent (;o)). One of the best books on the subject (and many others!) is Jean Dieudonné's Calcul Infinitésimal.

Comment: French is my first language, so that will do it, thank you!

Comment: Fine! It's also part what is taught in ‘classes préparatoires’.

Comment: I suspect that the French curriculum is generally more thorough than in North America, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: That's a complex matter. I would say, *was* more thorough. In some of those classes préparatoires, it can very hard. I've  justs seen  aproblem given to 1st year students about… the construction of ordinals. But that remains very specific.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. For instance, $f_1(x) = x^2$ and $f_2(x) = x^2 - x$; $g_1(x) = g_2(x) = x^2$. Then look at 
$$
(f_1 - f_2) (x) = x \\
(g_1 - g_2) (x) = 0
$$
which are clearly not asymptotically equivalent.