# Question about the definition of asymptotic equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, asymptotics

I've stumbled upon two different definitions of asymptotic equivalence (very similar but not quite the same): given two functions $f$ and $g$ with $g\neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ we say that they are asymptotically equivalent at $x_0$ if:
$$\text{DEF 1: }\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1 \qquad \qquad \text{DEF 2: }\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\ell \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$$
They don't seem to be equivalent, since for example $2x \sim_2 x$ but $2x \not\sim_1 x$. Personally I feel that the second one is preferable since is more general (and intuitively it makes sense that $2x$ and $x$ are asimptotically equivalent), but I found more often the first one.

Furthermore, I am interested in a specific property of asymptotic equivalence, that is the integration of the equivalence (meaning that if $f \sim g$ then $\int f \sim \int g$). I found some posts that say that this property is satisfied (for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439372/properties-of-asymptotic-analysis)) and some posts that say the opposite ([this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88699/integrating-an-asymptotic?noredirect=1&lq=1)). It seems from what I've read that with def 2 this property is satisfied, while with def 1 not necessarily (for example, the counterexample made in the comments of the second post that I linked).

So the problem is that I'm a bit confused by these (apparently, maybe) discordant informations, and I'm trying to put some order and clarification in all this. Any enlightenment?

Comment: There are many notions in mathematics whose precise formulation can vary with the author -- do rings contain a multiplicative identity, do normal topological spaces satisfy the Hausdorff separation condition, does $\log$ (used without an explicit base) mean base-$10$ logarithm or base-$e$-logarithm, does "countable" include "finite", does $\subset$ mean *proper* subset, does "smooth function" mean the function is $C^1$ or $C^{\infty},$ is $0$ a natural number, etc. You've apparently found the same is true for "asymptotic". In my own writing (handouts to students), **(continued)**

Comment: I distinguished between these two by calling the stronger version "asymptotic" and the weaker version "order". Of possible interest is a scale of "asymptotic-like" equivalences I discuss in [this 22 May 2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/S7X-C-FglaQ/m/Xhlkm6ii3dMJ), the most significant being *asymptote* (difference approaches zero), *asymptotic* (ratio approaches one), *order* (ratio is bounded away from zero and infinity), *exponential order* (logarithms are asymptotic). [Note: Here I'm using the notion "exponential order" **(continued)**

Comment: quantified by non-negative real numbers, and not the big-Oh notion one encounters, for example, when studying Laplace transforms in an elementary ODE course. The quantified notion is used in complex analysis, and unfortunately the same term -- exponential order -- is used is for both notions. The big-Oh version is the better known usage because it occurs in less advanced mathematics.]